# 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elemnt_by_name', Selenium unit test

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, testing

I have tried to do some unit tests using Selenium guide:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html

Also find this youtube tutorial but, this didn't help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_sIPPA4euw

And suddenly, I'm stuck on error and I can't handle this. Error:

Urz╣dzenie do│╣czone do komputera nie dzia│a. <- Its says "Device conected to pc don't work"

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59733/devtools/browser/b08ba32b-aab7-4000-a232-17ee5f8ee262
[2412:14716:0131/030125.624:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(185)] Unable to create cache
[15264:6784:0131/030127.670:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[15264:6784:0131/030127.671:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
[15264:6784:0131/030127.671:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(235)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[15264:10740:0131/030127.672:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [03:01:27.672] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1050 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Urz╣dzenie do│╣czone
 do komputera nie dzia│a. (0x1F)
[15264:10740:0131/030127.673:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [03:01:27.673] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1050 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Urz╣dzenie do│╣czone
 do komputera nie dzia│a. (0x1F)
[15264:6784:0131/030127.685:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(239)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_login (__main__.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thein\PycharmProjects\socialMeUp\main\tests\main.py", line 16, in test_login
    login.search_username = "admin"
  File "C:\Users\thein\PycharmProjects\socialMeUp\main\tests\element.py", line 7, in __set__
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
  File "C:\Users\thein\PycharmProjects\socialMeUp\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 78, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Users\thein\PycharmProjects\socialMeUp\main\tests\element.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    lambda d: driver.find_elemnt_by_name(self.locator))
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elemnt_by_name'
```

Code:

main.py

```
import time
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import page


class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"E:\operadriver\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')

    def test_login(self):
        login = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
        time.sleep(3)
        login.search_username = "admin"
        login.search_password = "haslo"
        time.sleep(3)
        login.click_login()
        time.sleep(3)
        assert login.is_login()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

page.py:

```
from locator import LoginPageLocator, MainPageLocator
from element import BasePageElement


class SearchUsername(BasePageElement):
    locator = "username"


class SearchPassword(BasePageElement):
    locator = "password"


class BasePage(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver


class MainPage(BasePage):

    def is_title_matches(self):
        return "Python" in self.driver.title

    def click_add_photo(self):
        element = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocator.ADD_PHOTO)
        element.click()


class LoginPage(BasePage):

    search_username = SearchUsername()
    search_password = SearchPassword()

    def is_login(self):
        return 'Profile' in self.driver.page_source

    def click_login(self):
        element = self.driver.find_element(*LoginPageLocator.SUBMIT_BUTTON)
        element.click()
```

element.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class BasePageElement(object):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        driver = obj.driver
        WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
            lambda d: driver.find_elemnt_by_name(self.locator))
        driver.find_elemnt_by_name(self.locator).clear()
        driver.find_elemnt_by_name(self.locator).send_keys(value)

    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        driver = obj.driver
        WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
            lambda d: driver.find_elemnt_by_name(self.locator))
        element = driver.find_elemnt_by_name(self.locator)
        return element.get_attribute("value")
```

locator.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class MainPageLocator(object):
    ADD_PHOTO = (By.NAME, 'addPhoto')


class LoginPageLocator(object):
    SUBMIT_BUTTON = (By.NAME, 'submit_button')
```

Comment: You have a spelling error in elemnt, should be element

Comment: @user1470034 Omg, I'm literally blind at the moment, time to sleep, thx

Comment: Been there before, keep at it and keep practicing